# RAM performance comparison of User mode vs Kernel mode

Tags: linux, performance, memory, kernel, ram

Unlike Kernel mode, User mode uses address translation due to the use of virtual memory. So it seems that there must be a trade-off for translating memory addresses when an access occurs (Even if there is no TLB miss).

Since Kernel mode accesses RAM directly without any address translation, Is there any performance gain in RAM if we run a code in Kernel mode rather than User mode?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any performance gain in RAM if we run a code in Kernel mode rather than User mode?

Probably not. The [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) is always used. It is just configured differently for kernel mode and user mode (so the "address translation" for kernel code might be some "identity" function).

And [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) considerations matter much more than MMU. a cache miss could cost several hundreds of cycles or nanoseconds (to fetch data from your RAM modules). Also, [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) are costly.

But **you need to *benchmark***. See the ending [*Answers* section of P.Norvig page](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

(indeed, the kernel address space does not have any major [page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault); I guess -but don't really know- that on some hardware it could have *minor* page faults)

Read also about the [Unikernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel) approach.

Comment: MMU spends same time to translate addresses for both kernel mode and user mode?!

Comment: I believe that yes, but I have not measured. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I have no idea because I dunno how MMU works, but I think it should take a time to do translation on MMU, Is there any docs about how kernel setups MMU to do translation?

Comment: As I wrote, the MMU is *always* working. I don'rt believe it works slower when configured for a "trivial" address translation. Likewise the ALU takes the same amount of time to add 0 than to add 1234567

Comment: It's not like a simple ADD instruction. I think, if TLB miss occurs, MMU has to access page table then calculate new address. but kernel mode has no page table and thus there is no more access to RAM for translation.

Comment: AFAIU, kernel mode has *trivial* page tables